# How to create a JPEG programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, jpeg, lockscreen

I just try to program a WP8 app in C# which shows pictures on the lockscreen. So far everything works, but how do I create in code a JPEG image, which consists of an Image and a string?

The LockScreen should be then be able to change with

```
LockScreen.SetImageUri("Picture Uri").
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the image to the isolated storage and use the following path: `ms-appdata:///local/<your-path-here>`.

Links:

- [Lock screen for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571206%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [Dynamic Lock Screen for Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8)

Comment: I know how it works, but how I can create a New JPEG image of a string and a image.

Comment: Oh, for that you can use WriteableBitmap to render custom control prepopulated with both the image and text.

Comment: Do you have any example.(I'm a beginer in programming)